# Re-arranging a table of values with VIM

Tags: text-processing, vim

I'm often in the situation of having to re-arrange a table of values, from this format:

```
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3
d = 4 e = 5 f = 6
```

to this format

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
.
.
.
```

in VIM. The fastest way to make it a column leads to

```
a = 1
d = 4
b = 2
e = 5
c = 3
f = 6
```

by first being in the first row, then `fb + ctrlV + $ + arrowdown + d + 3arrowdown + p` systematically. Is there a way to hastily re-shape a table in VIM? Perhaps a script in vimrc?

thank you in advance

Comment: Is that text representative? If so, maybe `:s/\v([^=]+ *= *[^=]+) +/\1\r/g`